# Is there an injective function which has the IVP but is not strictly monotonic?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, functions

> Can we find an injective function that shows IVP but is not strictly monotonic?

I know that there are functions that are injective but not strictly monotonic, like $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ if $x≠0$ and
$f(0)=0.$

Comment: IVP is satisfied by any continuous function on a closed interval, right?

Comment: @TurlocTheRed Right, but the OP is asking for a (not necessarily continuous) injective but not monotonic [Darboux function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Darboux_function

Comment: This answers your question: [Showing that an injective Darboux function is strictly monotone.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3032963/showing-that-an-injective-darboux-function-is-strictly-monotone) (the answer is: "no").

Comment: @AnneBauval the conditions for using IVP are f is continuous and (injective or strictly monotonic)??

Comment: I don't understand your question. A function satisfying IVP (i.e. a Darboux function) is not necessaritly continuous or injective.

Comment: @AnneBauval  In order to prove the existence of a unique solution to the equation f(x)=k we must have f continuous on [a,b] and k between f(a) and f(b) and we must have f is monotonic and we use IVP (here is my question) can we use IVP to prove the existence of a unique solution with f is injective but not monotonic

Comment: No, again, "in order to prove the existence of a unique solution to the equation f(x)=k" we must neither "have f continuous on [a,b]". nor 
 "f is monotonic". We must only have: f is an injective Darboux function. That said, I just discovered that your post is a duplicate of [Showing that an injective Darboux function is strictly monotone.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3032963).